# PHP Plugin for Intellij IDEA 15 not loading

Tags: php, intellij-idea, intellij-14, php-ide

I installed the Intellij Idea 15 IDE, and then tried to install php support for it. For that, I installed the following plugin. The IDE now shows the following error after launch.

> Plugin Error Problems found loading plugins: Plugin "PHP" was not
>   loaded: required plugin "com.intellij.css" not installed.  Disable PHP
>   Open plugin manager

I downloaded the plugin from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/update/index?pr=idea&updateId=22244).

Comment: Maybe install/reinstall the com.intellij.css plugin?

Comment: What is the plugin called?

Comment: "CSS Support" is what mine says.

Comment: Are you using the community edition or ultimate?  PHP is only supported in ultimate.

Comment: I was using the community edition.

Comment: I had a similar problem after switching from EAP back to Intellij 2017.2. For some reason, php plugin couldn't be installed so I uninstalled all of my plugins from settings, restarted the app and reinstalled the plugins I needed and things went smooth again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP Plugin depends on `com.intellij.css` which is only included in the **Ultimate Edition**. There is no support for PHP in the Community Edition